# Can anyone help me with this error related to passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, bcrypt

```
ReferenceError: User is not defined
    at Strategy._verify (C:\Projects\config\passport.js:9:5)
    at Strategy.authenticate (C:\Projects\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:90:12)
    at attempt (C:\Projects\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:366:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Projects\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:367:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Projects\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Projects\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Projects\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Projects\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Projects\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Projects\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Projects\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (C:\Projects\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:343:9)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (C:\Projects\node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:75:10)
    at attempt (C:\Projects\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:366:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Projects\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:367:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Projects\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: What were you doing?

Comment: Can you post more code snippet. it would be easy to help you out with that.

Comment: i am trying to use bcryptjs to hash password and save in database(MongoDB).I am not able to authenticate.I am using passportjs for authentication.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to create a User Schema in a **models.js** and export it to your **passport config file**

Comment: How can you say that without knowing that what he actually doing or defining with that user.

Comment: User is not defined so either he ddin''t create it or he didn't require it

Comment: please put your passportjs config code here also User Schema so i can define the error